# How to set the package not accessible for other package

Tags: java

Example: You have package A and B. Without setting class in A as protected. How do you prevent the class in B cannot access the class in A? (I met this problem during intern, my mentor said this is for the project independent. But I don't know how they made it)

Comment: You can put it in a module and not export it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an access modifier. By default, the member will have "package" access, which means that it will only be visible to other members within the same package.

You can make the other inter-package members accessible by declaring them as "public".

Comment: I mean, actually the file in package A are all public. However,  the class in the package B cannot use import com.xxx.A  . A package is not visible for package B. I'm curious how do they set it as that?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You can't explicitly prevent a specific package from accessing classes in another package. If you have good package structure, you won't run into this scenario to begin with.

Comment: @trvlr, the question did not ask how to do this explicitly.

Comment: @Rionash, you can't deprive access to a public member. That contradicts the definition of public. If you don't want the member to be public, then don't add the keyword "public" to the member declaration.

Comment: I think I figure it out. I thought they were just different package, but actually they are also in the separate modules. And in the modules dependencies,  these two module didn't add each other